# Working with a div that has a height of 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working with jquery to make a div resize to the the page height.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#top-section').height($(window).height() );
    });
    $(window).resize();         
});
```

That code works fine, but when I scale the page down, the content within the div doesn't stay within the div. The 'top-section' in this case scales with the screen while the content moves about freely. What can I do to constrain the content to this changing height div?

Comment: Can't you apply `height:100%` in css? and have the dimensions of child elements s well as in `%`?

Comment: not enough information to answer this question

Comment: You'll need to set the width and height of the content relative to the parent.

Comment: What info can I add to help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSk3N/1/)

```
$(function() {
    function responsiveReturn() {
        var windowW = $(window).width();
        var windowH = $(window).height();

        $('#top-section').css({'width': windowW +'px','height': windowH +'px'});
    }
    responsiveReturn();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        responsiveReturn();
    });
});
```